# I want to ignore fields from JSON only in few cases is it possible?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, model

My ModelClass

```
public class UserPojo{

   private String userEmailId;
   private String userPassword;
   private String userContactNumber;
   //setters and getters
}
```

I want to send UserPojo class object as json but In somecases I want to send with userpassword and somecases without userpassword is it possible?

In below method I want to send userPojo object without userpassword.
My **Spring version is 4.3.1.RELEASE**. I have **Jackson** libraries

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController{

 @GetMapping(value="/{userId}")
 public UserPojo getUser(@PathVariable("userId") String userId){

   //code goes here 
   //finally returning UserPojo Object
   return userPojo;
 }   

}
```

In below method I want to send userPojo object with password

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController{

 @GetMapping(value="/{userId}")
 public UserPojo getUser(@PathVariable("userId") String userId){

   //code goes here 
   //finally returning UserPojo Object
   return userPojo;
 }
```

}

I hope you got my point

Comment: How do you want to ignore the fields, in what context?

Comment: sure, did you tried? your json library should perform this automatically, if you need further requirements please explain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your requirement use `@JsonView`, if you want to ignore totally some field then `@JsonIgnore`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is achieved by using `@JsonView` annotation.

Here is a nice tutorial how to use this [feature](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this annotation at the field level and that attribute will be excluded from the JSON response.

```
  @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
  private float height;
```